# PS comparing multiple dates fom csv

Tags: powershell

I would like to ask you for a help. I have a csv with multiple ids and dates (id, date1, date2). I have found this script. It is working fine if I will type manually start day and end day (see example bellow). I need to get working days between multiple dates which are stored in csv. Can you help me?

```
$startdate = Get-Date -Date '2021-03-04'
$enddate = Get-Date -Date '2021-03-08'

$difference = New-TimeSpan -Start $startdate -End $enddate
$difference.Days

$days = [Math]::Ceiling($difference.TotalDays)+1

1..$days | ForEach-Object {
  $startdate
  $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
} |
  Where-Object { $_.DayOfWeek -gt 0 -and $_.DayOfWeek -lt 6}
```

Output I will get = 3 working days:

```
Thursday, March 4, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Friday, March 5, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Monday, March 8, 2021 12:00:00 AM
```

Sample input:

```
Id,Date1,Date2
1,22.2.2021,1.3.2021
2,24.2.2021,5.3.2021
3,2.3.2021,8.3.2021
```

Comment: please add to your Question ... sample input data [3 or 4lines otta be enuf], and the desired output for those lines.

Comment: Without knowing **how** these dates are written in your CSV file, there is no way anyone can give you a working solution. Follow @Lee_Dailey advice and add the required info.

Comment: Thank you guys. So my dates are in day.month.year format. There are multiple lines with 2 columns (start date and end date). Santisq code is working, but it is expecting format month day year. So reusult is calculated in wrong way. Expected output can be: Just list of days or list of days per id (i can add one more column id per each line). I tried to export santisq output to csv. It is working, but as i mentioned due to different date formant now working properly. I am thinking about converting all dates into year month day format first and then get working dates

Comment: Sample
Id date1          Date2
1  22.2.2021    1.3.2021
2  24.2.2021    5.3.2021
3  2.3.2021       8.3.2021

Comment: Just change this in @santisq s answer: `$startdate = [datetime]::ParseExact($line.Date1, 'd.M.yyyy', $null)` and `$enddate = [datetime]::ParseExact($line.Date2, 'd.M.yyyy', $null)`

Comment: BTW this information should have been in the question, not as a comment. @Lee_Dailey already asked you to show us that yesterday..

Comment: Thanks Theo. Sample input added to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your csv and write out the working days between every `Date1` and `Date2`, you can do something like below.

As commented, we needed to see what format the dates in the file have and that appears to be `d.M.yyyy`, so the code needs to parse that into real DateTime objects first:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\input.csv'
foreach($item in $data) {
    $startdate = [datetime]::ParseExact($item.Date1, 'd.M.yyyy', $null)
    $enddate   = [datetime]::ParseExact($item.Date2, 'd.M.yyyy', $null)
    # subtracting DateTime objects from each other will return a TimeSpan object
    $datediff  = $enddate - $startdate
    $days      = [Math]::Ceiling($datediff.TotalDays) + 1

    Write-Host "`r`nWorking days between $($startdate.ToLongDateString()) and $($enddate.ToLongDateString())" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    1..$days | ForEach-Object {                  # or use: for($i = 0; $i -lt $days; $i++) {..}
        switch ($startdate.DayOfWeek.value__) {
            { 1..5 -contains $_ } {Write-Host $startdate.ToLongDateString() }
        }
        $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
    }
}
```

Output using your example csv

```
Working days between Monday, February 22, 2021 12:00:00 AM and Monday, March 1, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Monday, February 22, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Tuesday, February 23, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Wednesday, February 24, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Thursday, February 25, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Friday, February 26, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Monday, March 1, 2021 12:00:00 AM

Working days between Wednesday, February 24, 2021 12:00:00 AM and Friday, March 5, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Wednesday, February 24, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Thursday, February 25, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Friday, February 26, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Monday, March 1, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Tuesday, March 2, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Wednesday, March 3, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Thursday, March 4, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Friday, March 5, 2021 12:00:00 AM

Working days between Tuesday, March 2, 2021 12:00:00 AM and Monday, March 8, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Tuesday, March 2, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Wednesday, March 3, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Thursday, March 4, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Friday, March 5, 2021 12:00:00 AM
Monday, March 8, 2021 12:00:00 AM
```

---

As per your comment to output a new CSV with all workdays added to the original input file's columns, You will have to experiment with how the output eventually is displayed in say Excel.

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\input.csv'
$newData = foreach($item in $data) {
    $startdate = [datetime]::ParseExact($item.Date1, 'd.M.yyyy', $null)
    $enddate   = [datetime]::ParseExact($item.Date2, 'd.M.yyyy', $null)
    # subtracting DateTime objects from each other will return a TimeSpan object
    $datediff  = $enddate - $startdate
    $days = [Math]::Ceiling($datediff.TotalDays) + 1

    $workdays = 1..$days | ForEach-Object {                  # or use: for($i = 0; $i -lt $days; $i++) {..}
        switch ($startdate.DayOfWeek.value__) {
            # not really needed to show every date with time info, as it will always be '12:00:00 AM'
            { 1..5 -contains $_ } { $startdate.ToString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy') }
        }
        $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
    }
    # output a new object with all properties from the input csv and added 'Workdays' column
    $item | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Workdays'; Expression = {$workdays -join '; '}}
}

$newData | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\WorkDays.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

This adds a column 'Workdays' where all calculated dates are semi-colun separated:

Once opened in a spreadsheel application like Excel, it wil look like this:

[image]

You could also choose to separate the workdays using a newline character by changing `$workdays -join '; '` into `` $workdays -join "`r`n" ``.

Once loaded into Excel, you need to set the Cell properties to 'Wrap text'.
The file will then look line this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Theo. Can you help me with last thing? I would like to export it to csv but it is not working. Line Write-Host is optional so I commented it and I will use it just in case I need to split each line of Date1 and Date2. It is working perfectly with that line or without it :). Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Juraj Sure, although a bit late for me now. Will come back on this tomorrow

Comment: Thanks I will wait :)

Comment: Thank you man. Did you update a code as well? I cant see any export-csv function

Comment: @Juraj Blast.. I had to rush out and totally forgot to paste the code in. Sorry about that. I have added it now

Comment: Thank you man. I love you. Just for the completeness maybe you can add to the newest code first line $data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\input.csv'
Maybe somebody will use it in the future as well. Thank you once again. My life is easier now :)

Comment: @Juraj You're right, added that first line now. (I definitively need better glasses..)

Answer (score 0):

Change Date1 and Date2 for the name of the columns on your csv.

```
$csv=Import-Csv 'your_csv.csv'

foreach($line in $csv)
{
    $startdate = [datetime]$line.Date1
    $enddate = [datetime]$line.Date2

    $difference = New-TimeSpan -Start $startdate -End $enddate

    $days = [Math]::Ceiling($difference.TotalDays)+1

    1..$days | ForEach-Object {
        $startdate
        $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
    } | Where-Object { $_.DayOfWeek -gt 0 -and $_.DayOfWeek -lt 6}
}
```